# gitlab Mirroring repositories push to remote repository

Tags: ssh, gitlab, repository, mirroring

I want to use SSH to automatically push my private Gitlab project to GitHub.com.
I configured ssh key with GitHub.com, and execute `git clone git@github.com:my-project.git` successfuly.
`sudo ssh -vT git@github.com` is ok

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([20.205.243.166]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi muxianliangqin! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3572, received 2912 bytes, in 0.6 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 6123.4, received 4992.0
debug1: Exit status 1
```

but use gitlab -> Mirroring repositories push failed.
Here are some of my Settings：

```
Git repository URL=ssh://git@github.com/username/project.git
Mirror direction=push
detect host keys
Authentication method=SSH public key
```

error:

```
13:get remote references: create git ls-remote: exit status 128, stderr: "git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n".
```

What's my problem？

This my settings on GitHub
[image]

This my settings on gitlab.
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you enter the **private** key in the repository mirroring settings on GitLab?

Comment: @sytech Github and GitLab Settings have been added to the details. SSH host key was returned after I clicked "Detect host key" button.

Comment: @gengen Did you enter on GitLab the public key of GitHub `aliyun-root-rsa` private key?

Comment: @VonC I add public key on github, private key  on `~/.ssh/`,then `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Testing with the `ssh -T git@github.com` command is OK. Are you saying that's not enough.How to set up private key on GitLab?

Answer (score -2):

The [GitLab Mirroring documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/#authentication-methods-for-mirrors) includes:

> SSH authentication is mutual:
>
> - You must prove to the server that you’re allowed to access the repository.
> - The server must also prove to you that it’s who it claims to be.
>
> If you’re mirroring over SSH (using an ssh:// URL), you can authenticate using:
>
> - Password-based authentication, just as over HTTPS.
> - Public key authentication. This method is often more secure than password authentication, especially when the other repository supports deploy keys

So double-check those settings.